# Repeated inserts with Primary key, foreign key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Can anyone tell  me how to do repeated multiple inserts on two tables with primary key, foreign key 
Here's what I've done. 
This is a very snippet of what needs to be done. 
StatusTable has around 200 rows. I am trying to split the details of this Status table into 2- Table1, Table2.

After inserting each record into Table1, I am getting the Identity column and this needs to be inserted into Table2 with some additional stuff. So if there are 200 rows in StatusTable there are 200 in Table1, Table2.

But thats not the way it is working. It is inserting all the 200 rows into Table1, then getting the Identity and then inserting a single row into Table2. I know why it is doing this. But not sure how to fix it..

```
     INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table1]
               ([UserID],  
               ,[FirstName].......)
     SELECT 'User1' AS [UserID]
               ,'FirstName'
     FROM [dbo].[StatusTable]

     SELECT @id =  SCOPE_IDENTITY()

     INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2]
                ([AccountID],[Status]
           values (@id, 'S')
```

Please suggest

Comment: Do each pair of inserts together. Create a forward-only cursor and read each row in StatusTable. For each row you can do what you are currently doing, i.e. insert into Table1, use scope_identity to get the ID, and use that ID to insert the corresponding record into Table2.

Comment: ANy column in the data (or combination of columns) that would make each row unique?  In the insert into table 2 statement, you can reference table one in the select statement.

Comment: How does a user differentiate one `StatusTable` row from another without using the identity value? Is the `UserID` column required to be unique? `UserID` + `FirstName`? `UserID` + `FirstName` + `Status`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the OUTPUT clause

```
 DECLARE @IDS TABLE (id INT) 

 INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table1]
               ([UserID]  
               ,[FirstName])
     OUTPUT inserted.id INTO @IDS          
     SELECT 'User1' AS [UserID]
               ,'FirstName'
     FROM [dbo].[StatusTable]

     INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2]
                ([AccountID],[Status])
         SELECT Id, 'S' FROM @IDS
```

Comment: I think you can skip the table parameter. OUTPUT inserted.id, 'S' INTO Table2(AccountId,Status)

Comment: Yes but often you want to use this in multiple places and with multiple values

Answer (score 0):

Try a set based approach instead of this single row at a time logic.  Load the first table, and then you can reference the first table and the data table in the insert to the second table, if you have something that makes each row unique.

you can use a select statement instead of a value list:

```
insert into table
select rows from othertable (or multiple tables...it's a select statement as complicated as you wish)
```

Pseudo coded:

```
Insert into table2 (datacolumns)
select table1.id, datacolumn 
from statustable  s 
inner join table1 t
on (whatever makes these rows unique)
```

Comment: This does assume that there is something that makes the rows unique, apart from their PK in statustable. If not, then this approach can be used but it will require that the PK from statustable is inserted into Table1. Not difficult, but you just have to turn off identity inserts on Table 1 while the data is be loaded.

Comment: As my answer includes " if you have something that makes each row unique"...and yes, if you include it, the arbitrary PK in statustable would work.  You could join it on every column, which works as long as the data is unique when every column is considered